# class in Jar how to get resource out of the jar in android (eclipse)

Tags: android

I have a jar project A, which will generate a jar, in this jar, some class should using some resource out of the jar,

project B will going to using the jar project A, and also contain some layout and picture resource which jar A will using.

I have not trouble in using these in Intelij Idea 12, but in Eclipse, I have problem, I success in build the jar in Eclipse, but crash while using in Project B,

any good suggestion on this?

Comment: the logcat do little help , I know the crash is caused by the sometimes the class in jar can not find the resource out of it.
for example, I am using a listview in jar project, (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
because, I am not outport the resoure file in the jar project, I just outport the class source file to form a A.JAR ..

Comment: then in project B, I am using A.jar, and also project B contains the resouce file A.jar Need, but it is just very strange in Eclipse, it often fail to find the resource, then crash,I am asking if some other way to fix this bug.

Comment: If project A is an Android project, the correct approach is to flag this project as a *Library* project and then reference it from project B as a *Library* project. I don't believe a JAR file can contain resource files like XML files, so that's probably why you get an exception.